# HIVE SQL Convert (UTC) 2018-06-19T14:01:17.000000 to timestamp ('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss' )

Tags: sql, hive, timestamp, utc, hue

I know the question seen simple and it should be a simple answer but I spent sometime in this and can´t resolve it. Some help would be really appreciated.
I'm using SQL on HUE Hive.

TO_DATE(col) works alright but only returns date, but not the time.
For what I understand the original format is UTC string

I believe the code should be something like and I'm probably misplacing the fields.

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(column_name, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

As a result I get NULL instead desired: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match **`T`** in your **unix_timestamp** conversion

**`Try with this syntax:`**

```
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("2018-06-19T14:01:17.000000", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

(or)

```
hive> select timestamp(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("2018-06-19T14:01:17.000000", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')); --casting to timestamp
```

**`Result:`**

```
2018-06-19 14:01:17
```

Comment: Thank you! :) that solved the matter.